# How to get image uri after uploading image to Firebase Storage?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage, android-glide

I'm working on a kotlin project that requires the user to insert an image using camera or gallery, and then the app will upload the image to Firebase Storage, and save the image uri to the FireStore.
After that i get all the image with glide and show it with recyclerview.
This is my item class:

```kotlin
data class Item(var uid: String?=null,
                     var productId:String?=null,
                     var productCategory: String?=null,
                     var productWeight: Double?=null,
                     var productDescription: String?=null,
                     var productIcon:String?=null)
```

And later, i show the image using this code:

```kotlin
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: itemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val produk=listOfItem[position]
        holder.kategori.text=produk.productCategory
        holder.berat.text=produk.productWeight.toString()

        //img
        Glide.with(context)
            .load(produk.productIcon)
            .into(holder.gambarBarang)

    }
```

And i use this code to get the image uri after uploading the image:

```
storageReference.putFile(image_Uri!!)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val downloadUri = task.result
                    val item = Item(
                        ""+firebaseAuth.uid,
                        timeStamp,
                        kategori,
                        berat_sampah.toDouble(),
                        deskripsi,
                        ""+downloadUri,
                    )
```

But when i try to display it using above method, the image doesn't show. The problem is the variable **downloadUri**. It doesn't get the right uri. I try to log it and get:`D/TAG: com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask$TaskSnapshot@6e38b25`. After that, i try:

```
storageReference.putFile(image_Uri!!)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val downloadUri = task.result?.uploadSessionUri
                    val item = Item(
                        ""+firebaseAuth.uid,
                        timeStamp,
                        kategori,
                        berat_sampah.toDouble(),
                        deskripsi,
                        ""+downloadUri,
                    )
```

But when run, the image still does not appear. I try to log download uri again and get:

```
D/TAG: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rongsokin-97e5c.appspot.com/o?name=product_images%2F1628401535415&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=ADPycdv0k03oF-49BTl61tKIC4Q-05J3cfOMqYpfUi9USXOMOGQmiOYalhVOSlRr6HP-ScqN6Hfv8NVrkI_qcU-CG6U&upload_protocol=resumable
```

And then i try:

```
storageReference.putFile(image_Uri!!)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val downloadUri = image_Uri
                    val item = Item(
                        ""+firebaseAuth.uid,
                        timeStamp,
                        kategori,
                        berat_sampah.toDouble(),
                        deskripsi,
                        ""+downloadUri,
                    )
```

After that i log the downloadUri again and get:
`D/TAG: content://media/external/images/media/85`
I know this isn't the right way because I'm only fetching the local uri of the image, but I'm doing this to find out if the way I'm displaying the image is wrong or an error in the way I'm fetching the uri. And this way successfully displays the image(though not with the right uri). Anyone know how can i get the image uri after uploading to firebase and then use it to show the image?

Comment: It's not possible for us to know why the image doesn't appear because we can't see the contents of any of the variables here, and we don't know what you're doing with the item after you create it.  Anything could be going wrong.  Please edit the question to show enough debugging details where it becomes more clear what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson, thanks for the advice, I've edited my question and add my class code and some log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call the `getDownloadUrl()` after uploading the file, or at the least, call the method on the reference path.

```js
storageRef.child("users/me/profile.png").downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
    // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
}.addOnFailureListener {
    // Handle any errors
}
```

Full example:

```js
val ref = storageRef.child("images/mountains.jpg")
uploadTask = ref.putFile(file)

val urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask { task ->
    if (!task.isSuccessful) {
        task.exception?.let {
            throw it
        }
    }
    ref.downloadUrl
}.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        val downloadUri = task.result
    } else {
        // Handle failures
        // ...
    }
}
```